# How to print data from a circular list in java?

Tags: java, circular-list

I am working with circular list in java. I am trying to print the data in the list but I am not getting the desired output. I am getting the output as

CircularList@55f96302

CircularList@3d4eac69

CircularList@42a57993

Kindly help to solve this problem.

Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Iterator;


public class CircularList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private static class myIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        int i = 0;
        CircularList<T> myList;
        Entry<T> iter;

        public myIterator(CircularList<T> list) {   
            iter = list.head;
            myList = list;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !(myList.size() == i)
        }

        public T next() {
            //System.out.println("next");
            i++;
            T nextvalue = iter.value;
            //Entry<T> nextnode = new Entry<T>();
            iter = iter.next;               
            return nextvalue;
        }

        public void remove() {
            if(myList.size() == 1) {
                myList.head = null;
                return;
            }

            if(iter == myList.head) {
                myList.head = myList.head.next;
            }
            iter.prev.next = iter.next;
            iter.next.prev = iter.prev;
        }
    } // end myIterator

    private static class Entry<T> {
        Entry<T> next;
        Entry<T> prev;
        T value;
    }

    private Entry<T> head;

    public int size() {
        int index = 0;

        Entry<T> before = head.prev;
        Entry<T> after = head;
        //System.out.println(head.value);
        //System.out.println(after.value);

        do {
            before = after;
            after = after.next;
            index++;
        } while (after != head);

        return index;
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        //System.out.println(head == null);
        return head == null;        
    }

    public void append(T value) {

        Entry<T> newnode = new Entry<T>();
        newnode.value = value;

        if (empty()) {
            head = newnode;
            head.next = head;
            head.prev = head;
        }
        else {
            Entry<T> before = head.prev;
            Entry<T> after = head;

            newnode.prev = head.prev;
            newnode.next = head;
            head.prev.next = newnode;
            head.prev = newnode;    
        }
    }


    public void insert(int index, T value) {

        Entry<T> newnode = new Entry<T>();
        newnode.value = value;

        if (empty()) {
            head = newnode;
            head.next = head;
            head.prev = head;
        }
        else {
            Entry<T> before = head.prev;
            Entry<T> after = head;

            if(index == 0) {
                head = newnode;
            }
            else {
                while(index > 0) {
                    before = after;
                    after = after.next;
                    index--;
                }

                 newnode.prev = before;
                 newnode.next = after;
                 newnode.prev.next = newnode;
                 newnode.next.prev = newnode; 
            }
        }
    } // end insert()


    public void remove(int index) {

        Entry<T> before = head.prev;
        Entry<T> after = head;

        while(index > 0) {
            before = after;
            after = after.next;
            index--;
        }   

        after.prev.next = after.next;
        after.next.prev = after.prev;
    }


    public void prepend(T value) {
        insert(0, value);
    }


    public void appendList(CircularList<T> list) {

        if (empty()) {
            head = list.head;
            return;
        }
        if (list.empty()) return;

        Entry<T> a = list.head;
        Entry<T> b = list.head.prev;
        Entry<T> c = head;      
        Entry<T> d = head.prev;

        a.prev = d;
        d.next = a;

        b.next = c;
        c.prev = b;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new myIterator(this);        

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");
    }

    public static void toString(CircularList<Integer> list) {

        String sol = "";        

        //for (CircularList<Integer> list : data) {
            sol = sol +"\n"+ String.valueOf(list);            

        //}

        System.out.println(sol);
        //return sol;
    }
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code for you (mostly). I didn't change variable names to be lowerCamelCase. It'll show up after it's peer reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you not to override the toString() method in that way. Your method is for printing, not 'returning' a string object. And it is totally different from the original toString method. Anyway, the result you are getting now is addresses of objects in circularlist I guess.

```
for(Integer data : list){
    system.out.println(data.toString());
}
```

and also you have to modify your code like this :)

Comment: He didn't override the `toString()` method. He created a whole different method altogether. The fact that the names are the same, does not make the method "overridden".

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. 'overriding' is 'redefinition', and his/her method is totally different from the original toString() method, so it is just a new method. Anyway this is a bad naming.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you've made `toString` a `static` method.  You also have its return type as `void` instead of `String`.  You need to write something non-static, with a signature `public String toString()` in your `CircularList` class, and have it return the `String` that you want to output.  I also recommend using the `@Override` annotation, so that the compiler will check that you've got the signature correct.

Comment: Additionally, if there was an `@Override` annotation on `toString()` (as there is on `iterator()`) the compiler would have informed OP that it had not been successfully overridden.

Comment: @DavidConrad - Absolutely.  Looks like you and I were typing that gem at the same time.

Comment: Also, don't forget that each class in the list must override the `toString()` method as well, or have some method to return the data items it contains.  For example, if my circular list contains references to my `Foo` objects, the class `Foo` must override `toString()` as well.  In fact, it is consider good practice that all classes override this method (as well as other methods; such as `equals()` and `hashCode()` ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString()` from `java.lang.Object` in your CircularList class.
Because it is not done yet, java prints the `java.lang.Object.toString()` which prints the memory address.
As a reminder, every object in Java extends `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: I don't think it's the memory address, but rather `Integer.toHexString(obj.hashCode());`

Comment: @Zymus: weel spotted ! then it depends on the hashCode() implemented in the current object.

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf doesn't get the data. It only prints a textual representation of the object, which includes the area where it is stored in memory(`@55f96302`). Something like this should work:

```
for(String str : list)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```